# Sort list with according to uneven value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a script for a library, that sorts authors in decending order of their Avg rating.

Below is my list:  ( It have author name + < space > + Avg Rating )

```
['Michael Crichton 4.71', 'J.K. Rowling 4.36', 'Sidney Sheldon 4.63', 'Narendra Kohli 4.9', 'Jeffrey Archer 4.62', 'Devdutt Pattanaik 4.42', 'George R.R. Martin 5.0', 'Dan Brown 5.0', 'Katherine Applegate 3.0', 'Eoin Colfer 4.25', 'Arthur Conan Doyle 5.0', 'Clive Cussler 4.66', 'Stephen King 3.66', 'Douglas Preston 5.0']
```

Below is what I tried: ( I split values with space, and appended in a new list, then sorted with third value, that is rating.

```
for line in rate_order:
    sort_list.append(line.split(' '))
print sorted(sort_list, key=itemgetter(2))
```

The issue is that some author name has three spaces in their name, so the third value is not rating. Can there is better ( or cleaner ) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rsplit`

```
>>> help(''.rsplit)
Help on built-in function rsplit:

rsplit(...)
    S.rsplit([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

    Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
    delimiter string, starting at the end of the string and working
    to the front.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are
    done. If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string
    is a separator.

>>> 'George R.R. Martin 5.0'.rsplit(' ', 1)
['George R.R. Martin', '5.0']
```

Another way to grab the last item of the split is to use an index of -1:

```
>>> 'George R.R. Martin 5.0'.split()[-1]
'5.0'
```

If your list is called `author_ratings` you can sort it in-place by doing

```
author_ratings.sort(key=(lambda(s): float(s.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I have no words. Brilliant. I didn't know there is a rsplit.

Answer (score 3):

You could split at spaces, and then take the floating-point value of the last component. Here is the whole thing as a one-liner:

```
>>> print sorted(rate_order, key=lambda r:float(r.split(' ')[-1]))
['Katherine Applegate 3.0', 'Stephen King 3.66', 'Eoin Colfer 4.25', 'J.K. Rowling 4.36', 'Devdutt Pattanaik 4.42', 'Jeffrey Archer 4.62', 'Sidney Sheldon 4.63', 'Clive Cussler 4.66', 'Michael Crichton 4.71', 'Narendra Kohli 4.9', 'George R.R. Martin 5.0', 'Dan Brown 5.0', 'Arthur Conan Doyle 5.0', 'Douglas Preston 5.0']
```

Note that the `[-1]` index extracts the *last* element (the first starting from the end).

Answer (score 1):

```
rate_order=['Michael Crichton 4.71', 'J.K. Rowling 4.36', 'Sidney Sheldon 4.63', 'Narendra Kohli 4.9', 'Jeffrey Archer 4.62', 'Devdutt Pattanaik 4.42', 'George R.R. Martin 5.0', 'Dan Brown 5.0', 'Katherine Applegate 3.0', 'Eoin Colfer 4.25', 'Arthur Conan Doyle 5.0', 'Clive Cussler 4.66', 'Stephen King 3.66', 'Douglas Preston 5.0']
sort_list=[]
for line in rate_order:
    sort_list.append(line.split(' '))

print(sorted(sort_list,key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex ([regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) matching in `sorted` function. Using this method of searching you can find rating independent from it's position in the string.

```
import re
print sorted(sort_list, key=lambda el: re.search(r'\d\.\d+', el).group(0))
```

In this code we use [regex built-in library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) searching by pattern `\d.\d+`.

Where:

> `\d` - matches any digit character (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
>
> `\.` - matches dot itself
>
> `\d+` - matches 1 or more digit characters

Also with [`.group(0)` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) we're getting result of searching by regex.

`lambda` function comes from [functional programming](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) and we're passing `el` argument into it which corresponds to each element from yours list while sorting.